How can I prompt an image generator to create scaled battle maps with a grid overlay for D&D or other table top games?
I have given instructions such as "grid overlay" "bird's eye view", yet the tool never seems to be able to scale properly. I am currently using Midjourneyon a PC with Windows 11.
